# Sharepoint 2013 PostSetup System.NullReferenceException after upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, cumulative-update, update, psconfig

I have SharePoint 2013 with build number = 15.0.4569.1506 now we have installed November 2018 CU, but when i run the product configuration wizard i got the following exception on step 8 out of 9:

[image]

I tried many things what I found on the internet but none of them has worked

Here is the part of the related logs.

02/20/2021 10:29:04  19  INF                          Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
02/20/2021 10:29:04  19  WRN                          Unable to create a Service Connection Point in the current Active Directory domain. Verify that the SharePoint container exists in the current domain and that you have rights to write to it.
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The object LDAP://CN=Microsoft SharePoint Products,CN=System,DC=dhphbud01,DC=hph,DC=int doesn't exist in the directory.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceConnectionPoint.Ensure(String serviceBindingInformation)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
02/20/2021 10:29:24  19  INF                          Entering function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
02/20/2021 10:29:24  19  INF                            Not spawning off the upgrade job, but rather running upgrade synchronously by calling SPFarm.Local.Upgrade() for inplace upgrade
02/20/2021 10:29:24  19  INF                          Leaving function TaskCommon.TraceToPsconfigLogAndUpgradeManagerLog
02/20/2021 10:30:15  19  ERR                          Task upgrade has failed with an unknown exception
02/20/2021 10:30:15  19  ERR                          Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.CheckAppOrphans()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.Check(SPContentDatabaseIntegrityCheckOptions options)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.ContentDatabaseDataIntegrityCheck()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.PreUpgrade()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken, Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean recursively)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Is there any chance to fix this problem? :S

Comment: I would first target to resolve the error in the log. Have you looked at [this post](http://sp-vinod.blogspot.com/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-service-pack-1-fails.html)?

Comment: That's not the issue and the SCP can be ignored. This is the issue: ERR Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseIntegrity.CheckAppOrphans()

Comment: Do u have any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the CLI version psconfig.exe instead of the GUI psconfigui.exe with the following command (elevated SharePoint PowerShell):

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

Now it gets weired: If this command also issues an error, execute it again without further troubleshooting, log analysis, ... In most cases, your update will perform successfully. If not: Post your errors again please.

Comment: I've already tried many of similar commands :(

Comment: Did you try to run my advised command _twice_ in a row?